# UIScrollView not displaying

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard, uitoolbar

I have a very simple application. 
There is a toolbar on the top, and the bottom. 
The bottom toolbar needs to be in a UIScrollView because it's buttons goes off the screen.
But when I test my application on a iPhone 4G, the scrollbar, and it's content, doesn't display. 
When I test it on a iPod 5G, everything is where it should be. 
I'm not using any coding currently, this is all being done in the storyboard.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with spring settings. Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @Suhas yes I am. What I've noticed is that it just disappears no matter where it's placed on the device's screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a difference in the screen size of iPhone4G and iPod 5 the UI will resize resulting in the shrinking of all added subviews.

There are two solutions to fix your problem.

1) Add both toolbars. Select the toolbar at the bottom of the screen and in the Editor menu

Editor > Embed In > Scroll View

This will make sure that the UI works out of the box.

2) This is the second way (I am guessing you've created your UI this way)

-> Drag a scroll view

-> Add Tool bar as its sub view.

-> Now we need to set the springs (In our case autolayout attributes.)

The image below will help you understand better

[image]

The first constraint "Height Equals" can be added as follows

Editor > Pin > Height

Now Select and edit the leading space to: attribute

and in the drop down menu select "Less than or Equal"

This is similar to setting "UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin" as the auto resizing mask.

Comment: Mine doesn't have a height equals constraint and my "Leading Space To--" isn't the superview, it's the toolbar.

Comment: Yes, as you can see from my answer you need to "Add" the Height Equals attributes by using the Editor > Pin > Height from Xcode menu. Have you added the scroll view as I've done in this image? If yes then even if "Leading space to" is Toolbar setting it to Less than or Equal must work. Why dont you use the 1st method I've explained? Its cleaner and easier.. :)

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that. I'll give it a try